# Losing my styles on PrimeNG update from 9 to 10

Tags: angular, primeng

Upon upgrade from PrimeNG 9 to PrimeNG X styles are broken. ui-something styles are renamed to p-something. There are no errors in the console and the behavior of some components is improved (e.g. p-inputNumber) - so it looks like this is a style only issue.

Styles are much improved but still quite broken if I add a theme in angular.json to styles: `"node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova/theme.css"`.

I would appreciate very much if somebody can provide some guidance on how to solve this:

1. fix styles one by one (this would be like creating styles again for the whole app)
2. wait for PrimeNG community to fix some bugs and transition from 9 to X will be a drop-in
3. wait for PrimeNG community to provide a guide for the upgrade

Comment: I am curious if you've solved this problem yet. I am noticing something similar with our application and it seems like a huge lift to migrate off of PrimeNG 9 right now.

Comment: @Tommo I ran out of characters in the comment so I posted you an answer.

Comment: I am still struggling to upgrade from V9 to V11~
We are using designer API. Now no matter what I do, it's just not picking up the custom styling on my UI elements such as button.

Comment: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/9248#issuecomment-847136721

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution seems to be a combination of 1.) and 3.).

They have introduced breaking changes with primengX. Transition guides [here](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/wiki/Migration-Guide) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W8lVy60wEOY). I found it helpful to look at their getting started for primengX LTS [here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/v10-lts/#/setup) even though we are using CE.

In addition to upgrading the packages you have to upgrade the styles (angular.json) in their example its LTS and in ours its:

```
"node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.css",
"node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css",
"node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css"
```

And now you "only" have to check each component about the remaining broken styles.